# How to correctly compare elements of 3 different numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, comparison

I'm trying to compare elements at the same index from 3 different arrays. When I try `if arr1[i] == arr2[i]` I get the `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. Here's the whole function:

```
def tmr(arr1, arr2, arr3):
arr4 = arr1
for i in range(arr4.size):
    if arr1[i] == arr2[i]:
        arr4[i] = arr1[i]
    else:
        if arr2[i] == arr3[i]:
            arr4[i] = arr3[i]
return arr4
```

I'm more familiar with C++ than Python and I really can't see why this doesn't exactly work. I also tried using zip like this:

```
for w, x, y, z in zip(arr4, arr1, arr2, arr3):
    if x == y == z:
        w = x
```

Comment: Is `arr1[i]` a single element, or a `row` of a 2d array?  This error is raised when `arr1[i] == arr2[i]` is a boolean array.  Such an array cannot be used in a scalar context like `if`.  Try these tests in an interactive session.  Pay attention to what the comparison of arrays does.

Comment: Be careful about `arr4=arr1`.  In Python that's simply a sharing of an object reference.  `arr4` points to the same object, not a copy.

Comment: [numpy.equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreting this as for the intended result in your last example using `zip`, try:

```
arr4 = arr1[np.equal(arr1, arr2) & np.equal(arr2, arr3)]
```

For the interpretation in your first code block you can use list comprehension:

```
list4 = [arr1[i] if arr1[i] == arr2[i] else arr3[i] if arr2[i] == arr3[i] else None for i in range(len(arr1))]
arr4 = np.array(list4)
```

Based on your example I'm not sure the default values for arr4 if neither `arr1[i] == arr2[i]` nor `arr2[i] == arr3[i]`, so have left them as `None` above.

The two approaches provide different answers, but if I'm interpreting correctly, the first is the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

numpy array functions `np.equal`, `np.logical_and`, `np.where` - vectorized/broadcasting

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([0,1,2,3,7])
arr2 = np.array([0,1,0,2,7])
arr3 = np.array([0,0,2,1,7])

arr4 = np.ones(5)*10


eq_idx = np.where(np.logical_and(np.equal(arr1, arr3), np.equal(arr2, arr3)))

arr4[eq_idx] = arr1[eq_idx]

arr4
Out[28]: array([ 0., 10., 10., 10.,  7.])
```